# Removing vowels from string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, replace

I am testing possible solutions for the following problem. The first two solutions I came up with 'disembowel' & 'disembowel_2' aren't running properly. I'm looking to figure out why.

Disembowel_3 is by far my favorite solution. But I feel like I have no right to use disembowel_3 if I don't understand where I went wrong with my first two solutions.

Could anyone help me figure out what's wrong with the first two solutions?

```
# Write a function disemvowel(string), which takes in a string,
# and returns that string with all the vowels removed. Treat "y" as a
# consonant.

def disemvowel(string)
  string_array = string.split
  vowels = %w[aeiou]
  i = 0
  while i < string.length
    if vowels.include? string[i] == true
      string_array[i] =  " "
    end
    i +=1
  end

  new_string = string_array.join
  new_string = new_string.sub(/\s+/,"")
  return new_string
end


def disemvowel_2(string)
  string_array = string.split('')
  string_array.delete('a','e','i','o','u')
  return string_array.join('')
end

# This is my favorite solution.
def disemvowel_3(string)
  result = string.gsub(/[aeiou]/i, '')
  return result
end


#tests
puts disemvowel("foobar") 
puts disemvowel("ruby") 
puts disemvowel("aeiou")
```

Comment: Hint: [`tr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-tr) is also an option.

Comment: #1 `split` without a deliminator will use space so your array becomes `["foobar"]` which is then appended as `["foobar"," "," ",null," "]`. #2 `Array#delete` does not take 5 arguments. That being said `string.delete('a','e','i','o','u')` would have worked just fine.

Comment: Your first sentence should be followed immediately with what is buried in a comment in your code. That is, the first thing you must do is state your problem.

Comment: @taman's suggestion is a good one. Alternatively, `str.delete("aeiou")` or `str.gsub(/[aeiou]/,"")`.

Comment: I posted an answer explaining some of the reasons why your first and second solutions aren't working. Besides, I suggested a refactoring to make the third solution shorter. Finally I suggested another way to do the same using **String#reject**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Minor changes would make disemvowel work correctly.  This is what was fixed, and why:

## Disemvowel

### The Bugs

1. `split` was changed to `string.split("")`.  `split` with no arguments will split by spaces, and `split("")` will split by characters.  With this change, the `string_array` becomes an array of each of the characters in the string.  This can also be done more succinctly with `string.chars`, which is the preferred method.

See:

- [String#split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split)
- [String#chars](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-chars)

2. `vowels` was changed to a string.  `%w[]` creates an array of the words, so when using `%w[aeiou]`, `vowels` was actually an array of 1 string `"aeiou"`.  This meant that neither `String#include?` nor `Array#include?` would work in the comparison to each character.  Changing it to a constant string meant that `vowels.include?` could match against a character.

See:

- [%w[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html)
- [Array#include?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-include-3F)
- [String.include?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-include-3F)

3. `vowels.include?` had no parens *and* was explicitly comparing to `true`.  The way that Ruby works, the result of the expression `string_array[i] == true` was passed to `vowels.include?`, which wasn't what was intended.

A couple of style tips that can help with this:

- comparisons to true should be implicit (e.g. don't use `== true`)
- use parens when calling functions or methods.

See:

- [Omit parens for DSL and keywords; use around all other method invocations](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-dsl-parens) section of the [Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide/blob/master/README.md)

4. `sub` changed to `gsub`.  The call to `sub` will only make one replacement in a string, so when calling with "f  b r", only the first spaces are replaced, leaving the string "fb r".  `gsub` does "global substitution", which is exactly what you want in this case.

See:

- [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub)
- [String#sub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-sub)

### First working version

The working `disemvowel` function looks like this:

```
def disemvowel(string)
  string_array = string.split("")
  vowels = "aeiou"
  i = 0
  while i < string.length
    if vowels.include?(string[i])
      string_array[i] =  " "
    end
    i +=1
  end

  new_string = string_array.join
  new_string = new_string.gsub(/\s+/,"")
  return new_string
end
```

and produces this output with your tests:

```
fbr
rby
```

### Cleaning up

1. Support mixed-case vowels.

   def disemvowel_1_1(string)
   string_array = string.split("")
   vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
   i = 0
   while i < string_array.length
   if vowels.include?(string_array[i])
   string_array[i] =  " "
   end
   i +=1
   end

   new_string = string_array.join
   new_string = new_string.gsub(/\s+/,"")
   return new_string
   end
2. Consistent use of `string_array` instead of intermingling with `string`.  Various uses of `string` occur when it's more appropriate to use `string_array`, instead.  This should be replaced.

   def disemvowel_1_2(string)
   string_array = string.split("")
   vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
   i = 0
   while i < string_array.length
   if vowels.include?(string_array[i])
   string_array[i] =  " "
   end
   i +=1
   end

   new_string = string_array.join
   new_string = new_string.gsub(/\s+/,"")
   return new_string
   end
3. Don't use a variable for "aeiou".  This is a constant expression, and should either be written as a string literal or a constant.  In this case, a literal string will be chosen, as there's no enclosing scope to constrain the use of a constant in the global namespace (in case this code gets inserted into another context).

   def disemvowel_1_3(string)
   string_array = string.split("")
   i = 0
   while i < string_array.length
   if "aeiouAEIOU".include?(string_array[i])
   string_array[i] =  " "
   end
   i +=1
   end

   new_string = string_array.join
   new_string = new_string.gsub(/\s+/,"")
   return new_string
   end
4. Replace the vowel character with `nil` instead of `" "` to eliminate the `gsub` replacement.

   def disemvowel_1_4(string)
   string_array = string.split("")
   i = 0
   while i < string_array.length
   if "aeiouAEIOU".include?(string_array[i])
   string_array[i] =  nil
   end
   i +=1
   end

   new_string = string_array.join
   return new_string
   end
5. Convert the `while` loop to `Array#each_with_index` to process the array elements

   def disemvowel_1_5(string)
   string_array = string.split("")
   string_array.each_with_index do |char, i|
   if "aeiouAEIOU".include?(char)
   string_array[i] =  nil
   end
   end

   new_string = string_array.join
   return new_string
   end
6. Replace the use of `split("")` with `String#chars` to get the array of characters to process.

   def disemvowel_1_6(string)
   string_array = string.chars
   string_array.each_with_index do |char, i|
   if "aeiouAEIOU".include?(char)
   string_array[i] =  nil
   end
   end

   new_string = string_array.join
   return new_string
   end
7. Reduce the number of temporary variables by chaining results.  This can minimize the number of individual variables that Ruby has to keep track of and reduce the variable lookup that occurs each time a variable name is referenced.

   def disemvowel_1_7(string)
   string_array = string.chars
   string_array.each_with_index do |char, i|
   if "aeiouAEIOU".include?(char)
   string_array[i] =  nil
   end
   end

   new_string = string_array.join
   return new_string
   end
8. Remove the explicit return to use Ruby's expression-based return values.

   def disemvowel_1_8(string)
   string_array = string.chars
   string_array.each_with_index do |char, i|
   if "aeiouAEIOU".include?(char)
   string_array[i] =  nil
   end
   end.join
   end
9. Use Array#map to process characters, rather than `Array#each_with_index`.

   def disemvowel_1_9(string)
   string.chars.map {|char| "aeiouAEIOU".include?(char) ? nil : char }.join
   end

## Disemvowel 2

### The Bugs

1. Replace `delete` with `delete_if`.  The `Array#delete` method will only delete exact matches, so you would have to loop over the vowels to make it work correctly in this case.  However, `Array#delete_if` gives you the ability to delete on a condition, and that condition is `vowels.include?(element)`.

See:

- [Array#delete](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-delete)
- [Array#delete_if](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_if)

### First working version

```
def disemvowel_2(string)
  string_array = string.split('')
  string_array.delete_if {|element| "aeiou".include?(element) }
  string_array.join('')
end
```

### Cleaning up

1. Support mixed-case vowels.

   def disemvowel_2_1(string)
   string_array = string.split('')
   string_array.delete_if {|element| "aeiouAEIOU".include?(element) }
   string_array.join('')
   end
2. Replace the use of `split("")` with `String#chars` to get the array of characters to process.

   def disemvowel_2_2(string)
   string_array = string.chars
   string_array.delete_if {|element| "aeiouAEIOU".include?(element) }
   string_array.join('')
   end
3. Change `join('')` to just `join`.  The `join` method will already join this way, so the extra param is redundant

   def disemvowel_2_3(string)
   string_array = string.chars
   string_array.delete_if {|element| "aeiouAEIOU".include?(element) }
   string_array.join
   end
4. Reduce the number of temporary variables by chaining results.  This can minimize the number of individual variables that Ruby has to keep track of and reduce the variable lookup that occurs each time a variable name is referenced.

   def disemvowel_2_4(string)
   string.chars.delete_if {|element| "aeiouAEIOU".include?(element) }.join
   end

## Disemvowel 4

String has a `delete` method that will remove all matching characters.  Given the vowels, this is a straightforward implementation:

```
def disemvowel_4(string)
  string.delete("aeiouAEIOU")
end
```

See:

- [String#delete](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-delete)

## Testing

I created a unit-test like program to do programmatic self-testing, rather than just displaying the disemvoweled strings to the console.  This will test each version of the function and report whether it passes or fails the test:

```
data = [
  ["foobar", "fbr"],
  ["ruby", "rby"],
  ["aeiou", ""],
  ["AeIoU", ""],
]

data.each do |test|
  puts "disemvowel_1   #{disemvowel_1(test[0]) == test[1] ? 'Pass' : 'Fail'}: '#{test[0]}'"
  puts "disemvowel_1_1 #{disemvowel_1_1(test[0]) == test[1] ? 'Pass' : 'Fail'}: '#{test[0]}'"
  puts "disemvowel_1_2 #{disemvowel_1_2(test[0]) == test[1] ? 'Pass' : 'Fail'}: '#{test[0]}'"
  puts "disemvowel_1_3 #{disemvowel_1_3(test[0]) == test[1] ? 'Pass' : 'Fail'}: '#{test[0]}'"
  puts "disemvowel_1_4 #{disemvowel_1_4(test[0]) == test[1] ? 'Pass' : 'Fail'}: '#{test[0]}'"
  puts "disemvowel_1_5 #{disemvowel_1_5(test[0]) == test[1] ? 'Pass' : 'Fail'}: '#{test[0]}'"
  puts "disemvowel_1_6 #{disemvowel_1_6(test[0]) == test[1] ? 'Pass' : 'Fail'}: '#{test[0]}'"
  puts "disemvowel_1_7 #{disemvowel_1_7(test[0]) == test[1] ? 'Pass' : 'Fail'}: '#{test[0]}'"
  puts "disemvowel_1_8 #{disemvowel_1_8(test[0]) == test[1] ? 'Pass' : 'Fail'}: '#{test[0]}'"
  puts "disemvowel_1_9 #{disemvowel_1_9(test[0]) == test[1] ? 'Pass' : 'Fail'}: '#{test[0]}'"
  puts "disemvowel_2   #{disemvowel_2(test[0]) == test[1] ? 'Pass' : 'Fail'}: '#{test[0]}'"
  puts "disemvowel_2_1 #{disemvowel_2_1(test[0]) == test[1] ? 'Pass' : 'Fail'}: '#{test[0]}'"
  puts "disemvowel_2_2 #{disemvowel_2_2(test[0]) == test[1] ? 'Pass' : 'Fail'}: '#{test[0]}'"
  puts "disemvowel_2_3 #{disemvowel_2_3(test[0]) == test[1] ? 'Pass' : 'Fail'}: '#{test[0]}'"
  puts "disemvowel_2_4 #{disemvowel_2_4(test[0]) == test[1] ? 'Pass' : 'Fail'}: '#{test[0]}'"
  puts "disemvowel_3   #{disemvowel_3(test[0]) == test[1] ? 'Pass' : 'Fail'}: '#{test[0]}'"
  puts "disemvowel_4   #{disemvowel_4(test[0]) == test[1] ? 'Pass' : 'Fail'}: '#{test[0]}'"
end
```

This will produce the following output:

```
>$ ruby disemvowel.rb
disemvowel_1   Pass: 'foobar'
disemvowel_1_1 Pass: 'foobar'
disemvowel_1_2 Pass: 'foobar'
disemvowel_1_3 Pass: 'foobar'
disemvowel_1_4 Pass: 'foobar'
disemvowel_1_5 Pass: 'foobar'
disemvowel_1_6 Pass: 'foobar'
disemvowel_1_7 Pass: 'foobar'
disemvowel_1_8 Pass: 'foobar'
disemvowel_1_9 Pass: 'foobar'
disemvowel_2   Pass: 'foobar'
disemvowel_2_1 Pass: 'foobar'
disemvowel_2_2 Pass: 'foobar'
disemvowel_2_3 Pass: 'foobar'
disemvowel_2_4 Pass: 'foobar'
disemvowel_3   Pass: 'foobar'
disemvowel_4   Pass: 'foobar'
disemvowel_1   Pass: 'ruby'
disemvowel_1_1 Pass: 'ruby'
disemvowel_1_2 Pass: 'ruby'
disemvowel_1_3 Pass: 'ruby'
disemvowel_1_4 Pass: 'ruby'
disemvowel_1_5 Pass: 'ruby'
disemvowel_1_6 Pass: 'ruby'
disemvowel_1_7 Pass: 'ruby'
disemvowel_1_8 Pass: 'ruby'
disemvowel_1_9 Pass: 'ruby'
disemvowel_2   Pass: 'ruby'
disemvowel_2_1 Pass: 'ruby'
disemvowel_2_2 Pass: 'ruby'
disemvowel_2_3 Pass: 'ruby'
disemvowel_2_4 Pass: 'ruby'
disemvowel_3   Pass: 'ruby'
disemvowel_4   Pass: 'ruby'
disemvowel_1   Pass: 'aeiou'
disemvowel_1_1 Pass: 'aeiou'
disemvowel_1_2 Pass: 'aeiou'
disemvowel_1_3 Pass: 'aeiou'
disemvowel_1_4 Pass: 'aeiou'
disemvowel_1_5 Pass: 'aeiou'
disemvowel_1_6 Pass: 'aeiou'
disemvowel_1_7 Pass: 'aeiou'
disemvowel_1_8 Pass: 'aeiou'
disemvowel_1_9 Pass: 'aeiou'
disemvowel_2   Pass: 'aeiou'
disemvowel_2_1 Pass: 'aeiou'
disemvowel_2_2 Pass: 'aeiou'
disemvowel_2_3 Pass: 'aeiou'
disemvowel_2_4 Pass: 'aeiou'
disemvowel_3   Pass: 'aeiou'
disemvowel_4   Pass: 'aeiou'
disemvowel_1   Fail: 'AeIoU'
disemvowel_1_1 Pass: 'AeIoU'
disemvowel_1_2 Pass: 'AeIoU'
disemvowel_1_3 Pass: 'AeIoU'
disemvowel_1_4 Pass: 'AeIoU'
disemvowel_1_5 Pass: 'AeIoU'
disemvowel_1_6 Pass: 'AeIoU'
disemvowel_1_7 Pass: 'AeIoU'
disemvowel_1_8 Pass: 'AeIoU'
disemvowel_1_9 Pass: 'AeIoU'
disemvowel_2   Pass: 'AeIoU'
disemvowel_2_1 Pass: 'AeIoU'
disemvowel_2_2 Pass: 'AeIoU'
disemvowel_2_3 Pass: 'AeIoU'
disemvowel_2_4 Pass: 'AeIoU'
disemvowel_3   Pass: 'AeIoU'
disemvowel_4   Pass: 'AeIoU'
```

## Benchmarking

I wrote a benchmark program to test the performance of each implementation.  Here's the benchmark program:

```
Times = 5_000
chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890!@#$%^&*(),./<>?;':\"[]{}\\|-=_+`~".chars
array = Times.times.map { |n| "#{chars.sample(n)}" }

puts "============================================================="
puts RUBY_DESCRIPTION

Benchmark.bm(15) do |x|
  dismevowel_1_report =   x.report("disemvowel_1:")   { array.each {|s| disemvowel_1(s) } }
  dismevowel_1_1_report = x.report("disemvowel_1_1:") { array.each {|s| disemvowel_1_1(s) } }
  dismevowel_1_2_report = x.report("disemvowel_1_2:") { array.each {|s| disemvowel_1_1(s) } }
  dismevowel_1_3_report = x.report("disemvowel_1_3:") { array.each {|s| disemvowel_1_1(s) } }
  dismevowel_1_4_report = x.report("disemvowel_1_4:") { array.each {|s| disemvowel_1_1(s) } }
  dismevowel_1_5_report = x.report("disemvowel_1_5:") { array.each {|s| disemvowel_1_1(s) } }
  dismevowel_1_6_report = x.report("disemvowel_1_6:") { array.each {|s| disemvowel_1_1(s) } }
  dismevowel_1_7_report = x.report("disemvowel_1_7:") { array.each {|s| disemvowel_1_1(s) } }
  dismevowel_1_8_report = x.report("disemvowel_1_8:") { array.each {|s| disemvowel_1_1(s) } }
  dismevowel_1_9_report = x.report("disemvowel_1_9:") { array.each {|s| disemvowel_1_1(s) } }
  dismevowel_2_report   = x.report("disemvowel_2:")   { array.each {|s| disemvowel_2(s) } }
  dismevowel_2_1_report = x.report("disemvowel_2_1:") { array.each {|s| disemvowel_1_1(s) } }
  dismevowel_2_2_report = x.report("disemvowel_2_2:") { array.each {|s| disemvowel_1_1(s) } }
  dismevowel_2_3_report = x.report("disemvowel_2_3:") { array.each {|s| disemvowel_1_1(s) } }
  dismevowel_2_4_report = x.report("disemvowel_2_4:") { array.each {|s| disemvowel_1_1(s) } }
  dismevowel_3_report   = x.report("disemvowel_3:")   { array.each {|s| disemvowel_3(s) } }
  dismevowel_4_report   = x.report("disemvowel_4:")   { array.each {|s| disemvowel_4(s) } }
end
```

And this is the output from the benchmarks:

```
=============================================================
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-darwin14]
                      user     system      total        real
disemvowel_1:     2.630000   0.010000   2.640000 (  3.487851)
disemvowel_1_1:   2.300000   0.010000   2.310000 (  2.536056)
disemvowel_1_2:   2.360000   0.010000   2.370000 (  2.651750)
disemvowel_1_3:   2.290000   0.010000   2.300000 (  2.449730)
disemvowel_1_4:   2.320000   0.020000   2.340000 (  2.599105)
disemvowel_1_5:   2.360000   0.010000   2.370000 (  2.473005)
disemvowel_1_6:   2.340000   0.010000   2.350000 (  2.813744)
disemvowel_1_7:   2.380000   0.030000   2.410000 (  3.663057)
disemvowel_1_8:   2.330000   0.010000   2.340000 (  2.525702)
disemvowel_1_9:   2.290000   0.010000   2.300000 (  2.494189)
disemvowel_2:     2.490000   0.000000   2.490000 (  2.591459)
disemvowel_2_1:   2.310000   0.010000   2.320000 (  2.503748)
disemvowel_2_2:   2.340000   0.010000   2.350000 (  2.608350)
disemvowel_2_3:   2.320000   0.010000   2.330000 (  2.820086)
disemvowel_2_4:   2.330000   0.010000   2.340000 (  2.735653)
disemvowel_3:     0.070000   0.000000   0.070000 (  0.070498)
disemvowel_4:     0.020000   0.000000   0.020000 (  0.018580)
```

## Conclusion

The `String#delete` method massively outperforms all of the hand-rolled solutions except `String#gsub` by more than 100X, and it's 2.5 times faster than `String#gsub`.  It's very easy to use and outperforms everything else; this is easily the best solution.

Comment: We can also get rid of `new_string = new_string.gsub(/\s+/,"")` if we change `string_array[i] =  " "` to `string_array[i] =  nul`

Comment: One thing is part of the other. To make it better, the first step is finding out what is wrong.

Comment: This is the perfect answer to the question asked and verbose enough to explain all the issues. Excellent work.

Comment: @engineersmnky Thanks!  I added some additional content to improve the solutions, test the different versions, and benchmark them, as well.

Comment: @Dan I added many new changes that you might find helpful, including testing and benchmarks.

Comment: @Michael Gaskill Why are you awesome? Not only did you present viable solutions to fix my code, I learned a lot about the intricacies within the Ruby language and your thought process. Thanks to everyone that contributed to my post

Answer (score 3):

This first solution is bureaucratic and has some errors, in code and style.

- You break your string into an array of separate char, but do it wrongly with **string_array = string.split**. Or **string_array = string.split('')** or **string_array = string.chars** (best option) or **string_array = string.each_char.to_a**. If you do `"asdfg".split`, the result will be `["asdfg"]`, not `['a','s','d','f','g']`, as you seem to expect.
- Then you don't use this (supposed) array, but keeps using the original string. If you intended to to this, why would you try to split the original string?
- Finally you move back to working with the array, changing it according to what happened in the original string. As you may see, you keep working with too many objects, more than needed certainly. This violates the KISS principle and not running properly is a consequence.

Your second solution, although much simpler than the first one, has the problem **engineersmnky** pointed. Array#delete does NOT take five arguments.

Finally, your third solution, although working fine, could be written in a much simpler way:

```
def disemvowel_3(string)
    string.gsub(/[aeiou]/i, '')
end
```

As I keep telling people here, you don't need an explict **return** in the end of a Ruby method. By default it will return the last value calculated, whatever it is.

Another possible solution, if you allow me to suggest, would be using **Array#reject** in the following way:

```
def disemvowel(str)
  vowels = %w[a e i o u]
  str.each_char.to_a.reject{ |item| vowels.include?(item) }.join
end
```

Comment: Sorry about that although since we are cleaning up `string.chars` reads better than `each_char.to_a`

Comment: Yeah. I'm a bit used to each_char.to_a but you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clean and easy to understand method.

First your vowels have been defined as a variable.

string#chars makes your string into an array of characters.

#select iterates over the array of your string looking at each item. If the item is not (!) included converted to it's lowercase version as a vowel. #select inserts that item into an array of items that met the criteria of items that you want.

#join without any parameters reassembles all of your characters, vowels excluded.

This will work with uppercase and lowercase letters. Also punctuation and spaces.

You will get back your input minus the vowels.

```
def disemvowl(string)
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    string.chars.select { |char| !vowels.include?(char.downcase) }.join
end


#p disemvowl('string') # => "strng"

#p disemvowl('s trin  g!?') # => "s trn  g!?"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are several different ways of writing a method to eliminate your vowels. They are broken up into two categories, destructive and nondestructive. The notes with the methods give more details about these methods. For the most part the difference between methods in each category is formatting. There are additional notes where further details are needed. I hope this is helpful.

```
# These methods are what is referred to as destructive. 
# delete!() will delete from the original item

def disemvowl(string)
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    string.each_char { |char| vowels.include?(char.downcase) ? string.delete!(char) : nil }
end

def disemvowl(string)
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    string.each_char { |char| string.delete!(char) if vowels.include?(char.downcase) }
end

def disemvowl(string)
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    string.each_char { |char|
        string.delete!(char) if vowels.include?(char.downcase)
    }
end

def disemvowl(string)
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    string.each_char do |char|
        string.delete!(char) if vowels.include?(char.downcase)
    end
end

# These are nondestructive
# The original is not modified and you are returning a string of selected items.
# Do not forget to flip your operation with (!)

def disemvowl(string)
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    string_new = ''
    string.each_char { |char| !vowels.include?(char.downcase) ? string_new += char : nil }
    string_new
end

def disemvowl(string)
     vowels = 'aeiou'
     string_new = ''
     string.each_char { |char| string_new += char if !vowels.include?(char.downcase) }
     string_new
end

def disemvowl(string)
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    string_new = ''
    string.each_char { |char| 
        string_new += char if !vowels.include?(char.downcase) 
    }
    string_new
end

def disemvowl(string)
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    string.each_char do |char|
        string.delete!(char) if !vowels.include?(char.downcase)
    end
end

# This is what I would do if nondestructive is desired.
# This was my original submission. It is explained step by step there.
# There are many ways to perform a task. 
# Because sometimes it matters how you achieve your outcome.
# I created this more elaborate response.

def disemvowl(string)
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    string.chars.select { |char| !vowels.include?(char.downcase) }.join
end

# This is what I would do if changing the original is desired. 
# This is an if else statement with Ternary Operators ? :
# I use logic as much as possible because it will out perform calling a function to do the same thing
# |thing| this is true about(thing) ? this will happen : <= or this }
# In this case I am saying |char| true(char) ? delete char from string : do nothing }

def disemvowl(string)
    vowels = 'aeiou'    
    string.each_char { |char| vowels.include?(char.downcase) ? string.delete!(char) : nil }
end


#p disemvowl('string') # => "strng"

#p disemvowl('As trIin  g!?') # => "s trn  g!?"
```